# Inserting at the end of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote a function for inserting a node at the end of a linked list. When I run the program, and when I call this function, the program just stops working.

Here is the function:

```
void insert(node **head, int x) {
    node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->data = x;
    new->next = NULL;

    node *temp = *head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new;
}
```

Can anyone tell where did it go wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In general, "just stops working" is not an adequate description of a problem.  Does it go into an infinite loop; does it crash with a segmentation fault or equivalent; or is it something else?  One of the questions to consider is "what did the debugger show?"  Another is "what did print statements show happening when they were added to the code?"  One or the other of those techniques is a necessary step to working out what's going wrong.  Consider creating an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When `while` loop terminates `temp` is `NULL`. So `temp -> next` will generate `Segmentation Fault`.

   Instead of `while(temp!=NULL)` you should use `while(temp->next!=NULL)`.
2. What if `head` is `NULL`? (Empty linked list)
   For that check whether `head` is `NULL` or not.
3. Also what if `malloc` failed?

So the solution will be:

```
node *insert(node **head, int x)
{
    node *new = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));        
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    new->data = x;
    new->next = NULL;

    node *temp = *head;
    if (temp == NULL) {
        *head = new;
    }
    else {
        while (temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = new;
    }

    return new;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `node**` to iterate. So it doesn't matter, if the list is empty or not. Iterate until you find a node whose `next` is `NULL`. You can allocate the memory right on target.

```
void insert( node **head, int x){

    node **ptr_new = head;
    while( *ptr_new != NULL ){
        ptr_new = &((*ptr_new)->next);
    }

    // now temp refers either to head or to next of the last node.
    *ptr_new = malloc( sizeof(node) );
    if ( *ptr_new != NULL )
    {
        (*ptr_new)->next = NULL;
        (*ptr_new)->data = x;
    }
}
```

In contrast to your original code you have a pointer to pointer in which the address of the new node is stored. In your original you iterated while `temp` was not `NULL`.

```
while (temp != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

After this `while` loop `temp==NULL`, because this is the termination condition of your loop. Because of that your program stops working here `temp->next = new;`

Comment: You should also check that the `malloc()` succeeds — but the technique is interesting.  Steve Maguire describes it in "Writing Solid Code", too.  It's advantage is that it avoids special cases — and hence helps reduce code bloat.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

- The `temp` pointer is pushed to the end of the list until it becomes `NULL`, by then it is too late to store the new pointer to its `next` member, and attempting that invokes undefined behavior (`Segmentation fault` on your system).
- If the list is empty, you cannot store the new item this way even if you stopped the loop when `temp->next == NULL`.

It is also desirable to avoid using C++ keywords to name variables in C code as it would make it more difficult to migrate the code to C++, should the need arise to do so.

Also it would be more correct to test if `malloc` failed and return the pointer to the new node or `NULL` on failure.

Here is a corrected version:

```
node *insert(node **head, int x) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->data = x;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        node *temp = *head;
        if (temp == NULL) {
            *head = new_node;
        } else {
            while (temp->next != NULL) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = new_node;
        }
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

You can also use a pointer to pointer to iterate over the list: it is slightly more sophisticated but shorter as you have only one test to find the location to store the `new` pointer:

```
node *insert(node **head, int x) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->data = x;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        node **np = head;
        while (*np) {
            np = &(*np)->next;
        }
        *np = new_node;
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

Comment: I like the second method. Thanks!